# Trying to backup a corrupted dynamic hdd

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, backup, clone

I think one of my drives is starting to fail.
Sometimes it becomes unavailable all of sudden, and when I try to access files on that specific drive, File Explorer tells me it's an invalid path.

Ran chkdsk /f overnight but still fails from time to time so I'm trying to backup it before doing further troubleshooting.
The disk also failed the vendor's Short DST.

I just got an external 2TB drive so I can backup my files but I'm not really sure if I should just clone the drive or make an image backup. And which software should I use for this purpose.

For some reason the disk appears as dynamic in disk management so most of the tools I've found around the web couldn't help because they don't deal with dynamic disks. I have no recollection of ever changing the drive to dynamic btw. Disk management also shows it as "Healthy (At risk)"

Basically my question is: Should I clone or make an image of it?
And will I be able to repair the disk?

EDIT: the disk I'm trying to clone is NOT the System one. It is, though, the installdir for most of my games and heavy duty software. And it also has a lot of media files, like music and family photos.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think one of my drives is starting to fail.* Yes, it is.

*Should I clone or make an image of it?* Cloning is imaging; different software tools call it by different names.

*For some reason the disk appears as dynamic in Disk Management...* Dynamic Disks were a Windows 7 thing; Microsoft recommends against them now.

*will I be able to repair the disk?* If you can't complete a CHKDSK/F, probably not, so clone, image, or copy the disk however you can, promptly.

Comment: Thanks, for the time being I just started copying stuff with the stock copy paste function and saving what I can since most tools I found don't work with dynamic disks.
So far it's doing it's job. Slowly, but doing it.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/212545/copy-a-bad-drive-to-a-new-drive?rq=1